# Create a python script to simulate a Matlab file and store results

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I have recently started working as a student assistant and I have to write a script in Pycharm (python) which is something new for me.

My task is to write a python script which takes a Matlab file (.m file) from the server, execute it and store the results of that file in a different folder.

I have created a function which returns the path of the matlab file from the server which I would like to simulate as shown below.

```
def get_next_job() -> Path:
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 2000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.sendall(json.dumps({"task_name": "next_simulation_file",   "host_name": socket.gethostname()}).encode())
    received = s.recv(1024)
    m = received.decode()
    message = json.loads(m)
return Path(message["next_simulation_file"])
```

Now, my question is how do I initialize matlab from python to simulate this file and store the results somewhere.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use subprocess module for the task. Let us assume you can run/execute your MatLab script via command: `matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r matlab_command`.

Then you should add a line in your script:

```
import subprocess
run_command='matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r matlab_command'
subprocess.call(run_command, shell=True)
```

I think `subprocess` will wait for the MatLab to finish and will continue the execution of the script after that.

Subprocess also has a method `check_call`, which can be used to detect whether the command worked or not. In any case, the MatLab has to be available for the system i.e. one has to have it installed.

Comment: Can I replace the "matlab" and "matlab command" with variables that I have in my script? For example , I already have a variable matlab_path which has the path to the matlab.exe and a variable res which has the path to the matlab file which has to be simulated. I would like to use these two variables so that the computer can identify which matlab version it has to use and which matlab file it has to simulate.

Comment: I think you should be able to start your executable as `/path_to_your_matlab/matlab  $options matlab_script`. Not sure how it works on WIndows though, but should also work if the name of the executable contains the whole path as `C:\\...\\matlab.exe`. The tricky part can be the *m files located remotely in some server - not sure that MatLab can directly run them. Perhaps you have to download the script first, set it to some location, and run as a local script.